# Meaning of $7 and $8 in a bison code

Tags: bison

I'm reading some Bison code for parsing a C program. Can anyone tell me the meaning of $7 and $8 in the following code because I only find 6 and 7 descriptions in two cases to describe a enum type.

```
enum_name:
      enum_key
      gcc_type_attribute_opt
      {
        init($$);
        PARSER.new_declaration(stack($1), symbol, stack($$), true);
        PARSER.copy_item(to_ansi_c_declaration(stack($$)));
      }
      '{' enumerator_list '}'
      gcc_type_attribute_opt
    {

      // throw in the gcc attributes
      merge_types($$, $2);
      merge_types($$, $7);

      do_enum_members((const typet &)stack($$), stack($5));
    }
    | enum_key
      gcc_type_attribute_opt
      identifier_or_typedef_name
      {
        init($$);
        PARSER.new_declaration(stack($1), stack($3), stack($$), true);
        PARSER.copy_item(to_ansi_c_declaration(stack($$)));
      }
      '{' enumerator_list '}'
      gcc_type_attribute_opt
    {
      // throw in the gcc attributes
      merge_types($$, $2);
      merge_types($$, $8);

      do_enum_members((const typet &)stack($$), stack($6));
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a rule, the tokens and other rules are given numbers starting from `$1`.  Any embedded code blocks are also given a number.  Thus, the first alternative in your code, we have (in outline):

```
enum_name:
        enum_key gcc_type_attribute_opt { ... } '{' enumerator_list '}'
        gcc_type_attribute_opt { ... }
```

Here, `enum_key` is `$1`, `gcc_type_attribute_opt` is `$2`, the first code block `{ ... }` is `$3`, the `'{'` is `$4`, `enumerator_list` is `$5`, `}` is `$6`, `gcc_type_attribute_opt` is `$7`, and the last code block is `$8`.  If the rules return values, you can find those values using the `$n` notation.

So, in the action that is the last code block, `$2` is the first `gcc_type_attribute_opt`, `$7` is the second one, and `$5` is the `enumerator_list`.

The analysis for the second alternative is similar.

The key point in the discussion is that the embedded code blocks are assigned a number too; since you didn't know that, you would be confused by the counting.